# changing the return type after compile-time

Tags: c#, arrays, function, return-value

i'm creating a class UML for a project in C# and i'm wondering if its possible to do something and want to check before I start writing it up.

I have a function that gets an Array of classes and returns one of the classes based on a 'level' int for its index. The array it uses will always be the same array, however the classes that it contains will be different depending on player input.

Is there a way I can set the return type to essentially something like 'undecided' and then in the function itself set the return type based on whatever class is at array[level]?

Thank you

Comment: use `dynamic` as a return type.

Comment: You can always return object

Comment: It sounds like you have a flawed design. You have a bunch of classes that are ostensibly related in some way. Define an interface that expresses the common properties between those classes. If the classes aren't somehow related, it's inappropriate to have one method to work with them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dynamic` as return type:

### Dynamic:

The dynamic type was introduced in C# 4.0. The dynamic type uses System.Object indirectly but it does not require explicit type casting for any operation at run time, because it identifies the types at run time only.

[image]

In the code above we are assigning various types of values in the variable amount because its type is dynamic and dynamic delays determination of the type until execution. All dynamic types variables enjoy the party at run-time.

### Example with `dynamic` return type:

```
class ExampleClass
{
    // A dynamic field. 
    static dynamic field;

    // A dynamic property.
    dynamic prop { get; set; }

    // A dynamic return type and a dynamic parameter type. 
    public dynamic exampleMethod(dynamic d)
    {
        // A dynamic local variable.
        dynamic local = "Local variable";
        int two = 2;

        if (d is int)
        {
            return local;
        }
        else
        {
            return two;
        }
    }
}


namespace DynamicExamples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExampleClass ec = new ExampleClass();
            Console.WriteLine(ec.exampleMethod(10));
            Console.WriteLine(ec.exampleMethod("value"));

            // The following line causes a compiler error because exampleMethod 
            // takes only one argument. 
            //Console.WriteLine(ec.exampleMethod(10, 4));

            dynamic dynamic_ec = new ExampleClass();
            Console.WriteLine(dynamic_ec.exampleMethod(10));

            // Because dynamic_ec is dynamic, the following call to exampleMethod 
            // with two arguments does not produce an error at compile time. 
            // However, itdoes cause a run-time error.  
            //Console.WriteLine(dynamic_ec.exampleMethod(10, 4));
        }
    }
// Results: 
// Local variable 
// 2 
// Local variable
```

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic`  and `Object` return types both work (though `Object` for non-primitive datatypes only)

You might want to consider [creating an interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx) for return types and implement it in your possible return value classes.

```
interface IReturnType
{
  void Do();
}
```

And :

```
class AReturnType : IReturnType
{
  void Do()
  {
    //do something
  }
}

class BReturnType : IReturnType
{
  void Do()
  {
    //do something else
  }
}
```

Usage is:

```
List<IReturnType> MyFunction( List<ConstantClass> constantClasses );
```

Edit: this does not change return type after compile-time, it's just a different approach :)